# Implementing a C++ ThreadLocal

Tags: c++, c++11

Do anyone know the best way to implement ThreadLocal in C++ whereby we can set and get values passed when neccesary.

I was reading about ThreaLocal in wikipedia and it says;

> C++0x introduces the thread_local keyword. Aside that, various C++
>   compiler implementations provide specific ways to declare thread-local
>   variables:

Do anyone know the gcc declaration for this and perhaps its usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually a part of whatever the threading library that your OS uses. In Linux, thread local storage is handled with `pthread_key_create`, `pthread_get_specific` and `pthread_set_specific` functions. Most threading libraries will encapsulate this though, and offer a C++ interface. In Boost, it is the `thread_specific_ptr`...

Answer (score 3):

With gcc you can use `__thread` to declare a thread-local variable. However, this is limited to POD types with constant initializers, and is not necessarily available on all platforms (though it is available on both linux and Windows). You use it as part of the variable declaration, as you would use `thread_local`:

```
__thread int i=0;
i=6; // modify i for the current thread
int* pi=&i; // take a pointer to the value for the current thread
```

On POSIX systems you can use `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_[sg]et_specific` to access thread-local data that you manage yourself, and on Windows you can use `TlsAlloc` and `Tls[GS]etValue` to the same end.

Some libraries provide wrappers for these that allow the use of types with constructors and destructors. For example, boost provides [`boost::thread_specific_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html#thread.thread_local_storage.thread_specific_ptr) which allows you to store a dynamically allocated object that is local to each thread, and my [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk) library provides a [`JSS_THREAD_LOCAL`](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/thread/jss_thread_local.html) macro that closely mimics the behaviour of the `thread_local` keyword from C++0x.

e.g. using boost:

```
boost::thread_specific_ptr<std::string> s;
s.reset(new std::string("hello")); // this value is local to the current thread
*s+=" world"; // modify the value for the current thread
std::string* ps=s.get(); // take a pointer to the value for the current thread
```

or using just::thread:

```
JSS_THREAD_LOCAL(std::string,s,("hello")); // s is initialised to "hello" on each thread
s+=" world"; // value can be used just as any other variable of its type
std::string* ps=&s; // take a pointer to the value for the current thread
```

Answer (score 2):

VC10 has new class named [combinable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492850.aspx) which gives you same thing, with more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

In MSVC it is called `__declspec(thread)` instead of `thread_local`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb(v=vs.80).aspx